# Casting matrix between cv::Mat to Eigen::Matrix and

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

Say I have:

`Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> someMatrixEigen = someMatrix();`

if I was to create a cv::Mat header (with type CV_8U), I should be able to do this, right?

`cv::Mat someMatrixOCV(someMatrixEigen.rows(), someMatrixEigen.cols(), CV_8U, someMatrixEigen.data());`

Then, if I have `cv::Mat anotherMatrixOCV`, to go back to Eigen, this should work too?

`Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> > anotherMatrixEigen(anotherMatrixOCV.ptr<int>(), anotherMatrixOCV.rows, anotherMatrixOCV.cols);`

Are the integer types compatible here? I seem to be able to get this to work when I use float and CV_32F, but the integer version doesn't seem to work (segfault).

Answer (score 0):

`CV_8U` would appear to be an unsigned type (specifically, 8 bits, e.g. `unsigned char` ), whereas your matrix is of a signed `int` type (how many bits depends on your compiler, but more than 8). You can try using `CV_32S` for the conversion, or `Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>`.

Comment: CV_8U is not a type, but a define `#define CV_8U   0`. (`opencv2/core/cvdef.h`). For the template you need an actual type, which in this case is `unsigned char`.